# Property Get doesn't keep value even if static

Tags: vba, excel

I often use the Filesystemobject in my Project, in many modules and I don't want to instantiate it every time new, when I need it. So I tried it with a Public property, which assigns a new Filesystemobject to FSO, if it doesn't exist. But every time the Property Get gets executed, the FSO is nothing and gets newly instantiated.

```
Public Static Property Get FSO() As Object
    If FSO Is Nothing Then
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    End If
End Property

Sub Test()
'at every line, the FSO is created again instead of using the old
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
Debug.Print FSO.GetTempName
End Sub
```

Am I just using it wrong or is it not meant to be used this way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264197.aspx) applies only to internal local variables when applied to a property get. You will have to use a local variable to get the expected result:

```
Public Static Property Get FSO() As Object
    Dim fso_obj As Object
    If fso_obj Is Nothing Then
        Set fso_obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If
    Set FSO = fso_obj
End Property
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot, i knew that the Static can't be completely useless.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for the clarification

Comment: Just curious: does that interesting technique bring a mesurable performance improvement ?

Comment: Not sure for FSO, but if creation/destruction of an object is time/resource consuming there can be noticeable gains over creating multiples objects. As for using a static property vs a global object I think it is more a style question. I expect the overhead of the property to be quite the same as a global declared with "as new", but it's just a guess and it should be properly measured.

Comment: @VincentG As new is not possible with late binding. I know, FSO should alwas work fine with early binding, but i see this as a reference for more often used objects.

Comment: @iDevlop Not really, i tried it with one time instantiating a new FSO for each call and once with this property. At 10000 GetTempName Calls, there where just a few seconds. But it was an improvement and i like it more than typing the same CreateObject phrase over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The property can be static but if the object is not, it is reset.

```
Sub Test()
 dim f as new fso
 Debug.Print f.GetTempName
 Debug.Print f.GetTempName
 Debug.Print f.GetTempName
End Sub
```

should behave like you expect

Comment: Thanks for the try, but i wanted a solution, where i dont have to dim fso in each module / sub, because i use it extensively over the whole project.